# `conditionalPanel` and `renderUI` within Shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I'm trying to get my Shiny app to work using the `rhino` package. I have successfully created a data module that allows the user to select a dataset to be imported. This next problem module is supposed to accept the dataset (it does) and dynamically render `selectInput()`s based on the variable names in the dataset (it does, but not properly when using `conditionalPanel`).

The goal: create an app that will complete a case-control matching algorithm. Have the user upload a dataset and select the participant ID variable, case-control variable, and 3 other  matching criteria variables. I would like to have the next successive input only render once the previous value evaluates `!is.null()` and `!= ""`.

I am including the problematic `inputs.R` module. You can see my 2 attempts at getting the `condition` to work correctly, but it won't with either method.

```
#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  useShinyjs()
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("idVariable")),
    conditionalPanel(
      # condition = paste0("input['", ns("idVariable"), "'] == ''"),
      condition = "input['idVariable-idVariable'] == ''",
      "This is a test and should show once the data is loaded." # not showing
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = paste0("input['", ns("idVariable"), "'] != ''"),
      ns = ns,
      uiOutput(ns("caseControl")) # currently displays after data is loaded
    )
  )
}

#' @export
server <- function(id, newFile) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, server) {

    message("Module ", id, " has been activated.")
    ns <- NS(id)

    output$idVariable <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(newFile())) {
        return(NULL)
      }
      selectInput(
        ns("idVariable"), "Choose ID variable.",
        choices = c("", names(newFile())),
        selected = ""
      )
    })

    output$caseControl <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(newFile())) {
        return(NULL)
      }
        selectInput(
          ns("caseControl"),
          span("Choose case-control variable.", bs_icon("info-circle-fill")),
          choices = c(
            "",
            setdiff(
              newFile() |> purrr::keep(is.numeric) |> names(),
              c(input$idVariable)
            )
          )
        )
    })

  })
}
```

This app works outside of the module format (i.e.-- one longer `app.R` style script). Also, removing the `conditionalPanel` displays all of the inputs at once. This can be used, but I'm so far down the rabbit hole of NOT understanding how the pieces work together that I would love to know where I'm falling short.

NEEDS:

1. dynamically render the case-control input
2. learn how and why the namespacing happens like this inside of modules
3. understand the JS evaluation of the `condition =` inside of `conditionalPanel`s when using modules.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To fix your `conditionalPanel`s provide the namespace via the `ns=` argument as you already did for the second panel. After doing so you could simply use `input.idVariable` for the condition. Also, when using `renderUI` it is recommended to get the namespace from the `session` object, i.e. inside the module server use `ns <- session$ns` instead of `ns <- NS(id)` (see https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/).

Here is a minimal working app using `iris` as example data where I added a simple `ggplot` for testing.

```
#' @export
module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("idVariable")),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.idVariable === ''",
      ns = ns,
      "This is a test and should show once the data is loaded." # not showing
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.idVariable !== ''",
      ns = ns,
      uiOutput(ns("caseControl")) # currently displays after data is loaded
    ),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

#' @export
module_server <- function(id, newFile) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    message("Module ", id, " has been activated.")
    ns <- session$ns

    output$idVariable <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(newFile())) {
        return(NULL)
      }
      selectInput(
        ns("idVariable"), "Choose ID variable.",
        choices = c("", names(newFile())),
        selected = ""
      )
    })

    output$caseControl <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(newFile())) {
        return(NULL)
      }
      selectInput(
        ns("caseControl"),
        span("Choose case-control variable."),
        choices = c(
          "",
          setdiff(
            newFile() |> purrr::keep(is.numeric) |> names(),
            c(input$idVariable)
          )
        )
      )
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      req(input$caseControl)
      ggplot(
        newFile(),
        aes(x = .data[[input$caseControl]], fill = .data[[input$idVariable]])
      ) +
        geom_histogram()
    })
  })
}

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  module_ui("mod")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactive({
    iris
  })
  module_server("mod", dat)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I noticed the changes that you made a have a follow-up question. Regarding the use of `===` and `!==` evaluations, am I correct that these are JS syntax since the inputs are using JS or ??? (hoping that wording and question makes more sense than I'm reading it as).

I noticed that I used `server` and not `session` in my `moduleServer()` function... oversight on my part.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yup. The conditions in `conditionalPanel` has to be formulated in JS. And while JS also allows for `==` and `!=` using `===` and `!==` test for strict (in)equality and are the recommended way.